# My Wordpress CSS file not working in my theme

Tags: css, wordpress, function, bootstrap-4, stylesheet

This is my file path:

```
D:\web server\blog.dev.cc\wp-content\themes\ablog\css
for java script file path
D:\web server\blog.dev.cc\wp-content\themes\ablog\assets\js
```

I have checked every code again and again but my problem has not been solved. I am trying to change `"` to `'` icon but not working and change some path on my CSS file and JavaScript but my CSS not show

```
// steel sheet 
      function ablog_add_stylesheet() {
              // outer styles sheet 
         wp_enqueue_style('font-awesome.min.css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/font-awesome.min.css'); // font awesome
         wp_enqueue_style('elegent-icons.css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/elegent-icons.css' );// icon
         wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap.min.css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css',array(), '4.2.1','all');// bootstrap css
         wp_enqueue_style('owl.carousel.css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/owl.carousel.css' ); // own file for slide css

            //own  CSS Files style.css 
        wp_enqueue_style( 'lookway_header_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' ); // main theme css file
        wp_enqueue_style( 'lookway_header_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/header.css' ); // header css
        wp_enqueue_style('themes.css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/themes.css'); // for artical
        wp_enqueue_style('responsive.css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/responsive.css' );  // responsive   
    }
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ablog_add_stylesheet' );


    // script

        function ablog_add_stylesheets() {
        wp_enqueue_script('modernizr-2.8.3.min.js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js' ); // script 
        wp_enqueue_script('plugins.js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/plugins.js'); // script 
        wp_enqueue_script('main.js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/main.js'); // script 

    }
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ablog_add_stylesheets');
```

When adding file not show any CSS on my theme

Answer (score 1):

In your code same handle use for two style i.e `lookway_header_css` please change that. You can use the following code to enqueue the style.css :

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'theme-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
```

And also just check that `wp_head()` and `wp_footer()` called correctly at **header.php** and **footer.php**

Comment: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54437268/my-wordpress-css-file-not-working-in-my-theme/54439874#54439874)  thank #tristup

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to put the `<?php wp_head(); ?>` somewhere inside your `head` and `<?php wp_footer(); ?>` at the end of the `body`, otherwise WordPress doesn't know where to print scripts and styles.

Comment: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54437268/my-wordpress-css-file-not-working-in-my-theme/54439874#54439874) thank man!